# How do I know if there is GPS signal？

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I wanna know if my map is using GPS signal,not the Wi-Fi or Cellular Data。
If that is possiblely, how can i find out the GPS signal strength ?

Comment: similar question probably. have you checked it already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632940/finding-gps-signal-strength

Comment: You can use the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the location of the map's userLocation property. A high accuracy indicates GPS. A low accuracy doesn't mean that GPS isn't in use, it may just be a poor signal